# A graph with n vertexes- how to print all possible graph combinations

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Suppose that we set the number of vertices in a graph as n. (we can set this by user inputs etc.)

I'd like to print all possible cases of connecting vertices using edges. (So, I'd like to print all possible (simple) connected graphs of n vertices.)

Also, for each case, I'd like to print degree of each vertex in each case.

Comment: Does order of vertices matter? Are cycles 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 and 1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 counted as two different graphs?

Comment: @OpDeCirkel, AFAIU [simple graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)#Simple_graph)

Comment: Oops. My example is wrong. But again are graphs (1-2,2-3) and (1-3,2-3) counter as two different graphs?

Comment: @defaultlocale yes. even if some graphs turn out to be isomorphic to some graph, they are treated as being separate.

Comment: Is the graph directed? If so - are you looking for connected or strongly connected graphs? These are two different things.

Comment: @amit undirected. and cases of simple connected graph. (Isn't strongly connected graph a directed graph?)

Comment: @user1441174: It is the same for undirected graphs. For directed graphs - a strongly connected graph is also connected, but not the other way around. `V={1,2,3}, E=(1->2,2->3)` the graph is connected, but not strongly connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive but simple solution would be to create all possible graphs, and filtering out the not connected ones.

Create a set of all possible edges. There are `n(n-1)/2` of those, and this will be the set's size.

Find the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the required set. This power set represents all possible graphs that can be created.

The wikipedia article also gives an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms) for calculating the power set of a set. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670862/obtaining-powerset-of-a-set-in-java) also discusses this issue (java)

For each subset created - check if it is connected or not. it can be done using a discovery algorithm such as [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). The graph is connected if and only if BFS discovered all vertices, when starting from a single (random) source.