# Finding all subsets of a given set of distinct integers recursively

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Given a set of distinct integers, I want to find all the possible subsets (for [1,2,3], the code should print `[1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,2,3], [2], [2,3], [3]` (not necessarily in that order).

There are a few solutions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498281/generating-power-set-recursively-without-any-loops)) out there but what I want to do is to **re-implement** the bellow solution with a new recursion and no `for` loop by passing around the indexes: (start = 0)

```java
public void forSolution(List<List<Integer>> res, int[] nums, List<Integer> list, int start) {

    for (int i = start; i < nums.length; i++) {
        List<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>(list);
        tmp.add(nums[i]);
        res.add(new ArrayList<>(tmp));
        forSolution(res, nums, tmp, i + 1);
    }
}
```

I thought I need to pass two integers to the method, one for keeping the record of index and the other one for keeping the start point, but I am having problem on when I need to do the index increment (vs start increment).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating power set recursively without any loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498281/generating-power-set-recursively-without-any-loops)

Comment: @Prune It's not really a duplicate. Please read the whole post before flagging it.

Comment: @Yar It's an exact duplicate (except your input is a list of integers, not a string of characters). The algorithms are exactly the same.

Comment: @Prune I edited the question to emphasis on the difference. Basically I just want to re-implement the `for` solution by passing around the indexes.

Comment: Check method 2 in this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-program-to-generate-power-set/

Comment: @Ari thanks for the link. That solution is very similar to @melpomene solution but I am looking for the `for` reimplementation.

Comment: Any loop can be replaced with a recursive call, the conversion is pretty much automatic.

Comment: @n.m well I know it should be doable I just don't know how :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the algorithm gets easier if you don't bother with indices.

The basic idea is that for any given sublist, each element of the original list is either included or not included. The list of all possible sublists is simply all possible combinations of including / not including each element.

For a recursive implementation, we can consider two cases:

1. The input list is empty. The empty list only has a single sublist, which is the empty list itself.
2. The input list consists of a first element `x` and a list of remaining elements `rest`. Here we can call our function recursively to get a list of all sublists of `rest`. To implement the idea of both including and not including `x` in our results, we return a list consisting of

   - each element of `sublists(rest)` with `x` added at the front, representing all sublists of our original list that contain `x`, and
   - each element of `sublists(rest)` as is (without `x`), representing all sublists of our original list that don't contain `x`.

For example, if the list is `[1, 2, 3]`, we have `x = 1` and `rest = [2, 3]`. The recursive call `sublists(rest)` produces `[2, 3], [2], [3], []`. For each of those sublists we

- prepend `x` (which is `1`), giving `[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1]`, and
- don't prepend `x`, giving `[2, 3], [2], [3], []`.

Concatenating those parts gives our total result as `[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1], [2, 3], [2], [3], []`.

Sample implementation:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub sublists {
    if (!@_) {
        return [];
    }
    my $x = shift @_;
    my @r = sublists(@_);
    return (map [$x, @$_], @r), @r;
}

for my $sublist (sublists 1, 2, 3) {
    print "[" . join(", ", @$sublist) . "]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1]
[2, 3]
[2]
[3]
[]
```

Comment: Very interesting approach! Thank you @melpomene

Comment: You are just hiding the loop in `map`.

Comment: @n.m. `sub mymap { my $f = shift; @_ ? ($f->(shift), mymap($f, @_)) : () }` Now I have a recursive map.