# Given an integer array (of length n), find and return all the subsets of input array using recursion in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, jagged-arrays

Suppose my input array is [15,20,12]
The required answer is a 2D array
The Required is output is as followed
[12
20
20 12
15
15 12
15 20
15 20 12
]

Comment: Is input array assumed to contain no duplicates? If it contains duplicates, must they appear in the output? For example, what is output for `[15,15]` input - is it `[[],[15],[15,15]]` or `[[],[15],[15],[15,15]]` ?

Comment: Sorry,we dont want empty array in answer. for input=[15, 15] the output is expected to be [[15],[15],[15,15]] @TomášZáluský

Comment: what you mean by  _we dont want empty array in answer_ ? - this contradicts with original question where you state it as expected part of output

Comment: Yes, i am sorry for that error. Actually the question was described like this. On executing the sample test case, it was not showing empty array. Sorry again. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear if it's homework or practical case. This is how would I solve it using Guava PowerSet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer input[] = {15,20,12};
    List<Integer> rev = Lists.reverse(Arrays.asList(input));
    Set<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(0, input.length).boxed().collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());
    Object output[] = Sets.powerSet(indices).stream()
            .filter(indexset -> !indexset.isEmpty())
            .map(indexset -> indexset.stream().map(i -> rev.get(i)).collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(toList(), Lists::reverse)))
            .map(List::toArray)
            .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] nums= {15, 20, 12};
    int[][] subsets = subsets(nums);
    for (int i = 1; i < subsets.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subsets[i]));
    }
}

public static int[][] subsets(int input[]) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    subsetsHelper(list, new ArrayList<>(), input, 0);
    return convertListToArray(list);
}

private static void subsetsHelper(List<List<Integer>> list , List<Integer> resultList, int [] nums, int start){
    list.add(new ArrayList<>(resultList));
    for(int i = start; i < nums.length; i++){
       // add element
        resultList.add(nums[i]);
       // Explore
        subsetsHelper(list, resultList, nums, i + 1);
       // remove
        resultList.remove(resultList.size() - 1);
    }
}

private static int[][] convertListToArray(List<List<Integer>> list) {
    int[][] array = new int[list.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[list.get(i).size()];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
            array[i][j] = list.get(i).get(j);
        }
    }
    return array;

}
```

1.As each recursion call will represent subset here, add resultList(see recursion code above) to the list of subsets in each call.
 2.Iterate over elements of a set.
 3.In each iteration
   Add elements to the list
   explore(recursion) and make start = i+1 to go through remaining elements of the array.
   Remove element from the list

Output:

```
[15]
[15, 20]
[15, 20, 12]
[15, 12]
[20]
[20, 12]
[12]
```

Comment: @Sarthak, Could you please check my answer and accept and upvote it, if it will work for you.

Comment: Hey, the function is pre defined as  public static int[][] subsets(int input[]).

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:**

1. This is my original work. No part of the solution has been copied from anywhere.
2. My solution works perfectly for 3 elements. However, this needs to be improved to work for arrays of other sizes. Despite this, I am publishing it so that OP or anyone else can extend this solution to work for an array of any size.
3. This question is close to the power set except for the fact that a power set can not have duplicate elements. If this exception is removed from this question, there are many solutions available e.g. at [1](https://www.baeldung.com/java-power-set-of-a-set), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670862/obtaining-a-powerset-of-a-set-in-java), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498281/generating-power-set-recursively-without-any-loops) etc.

---

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 15, 20, 12 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subsets(arr)));
    }

    public static int[][] subsets(int input[]) {
        int[][] subarrs = new int[(int) Math.pow(2, input.length) - 1][input.length];
        int[] indices = { 0 };
        subsetsHelper(input, subarrs, 0, 0, 0, indices);
        return subarrs;
    }

    private static void subsetsHelper(int input[], int[][] subarrs, int index, int i, int j, int[] indices) {
        if (i == input.length) {
            subarrs[index] = input;
            return;
        }
        int[] subarr = new int[indices.length];
        for (int x = 0; x < subarr.length; x++) {
            subarr[x] = input[indices[x]];
        }
        subarrs[index] = subarr;
        if (j == input.length - 1) {
            subsetsHelper(input, subarrs, index + 1, i + 1, i + 1, new int[] { i + 1 });
        } else {
            subsetsHelper(input, subarrs, index + 1, i, j + 1, new int[] { i, j + 1 });
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 [[15], [15, 20], [15, 12], [20], [20, 12], [12], [15, 20, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

public static int[][]returnallsub(int arr[], int si){

```
    if(si==arr.length)
    {int[][]ret=new int [1][0];
return ret;
    }
    
    
    int [][]rss =returnallsub(arr,si+1);
    int [][]tss=new int[rss.length*2][];
    
    int i=0;
for(;i<rss.length;i++) {
tss[i]=new int [rss[i].length];

}
       int k=0;
    for(;k<rss.length;k++) {
tss[i]=new int [rss[k].length+1];
  i++;
}
    
    
        int j=0;
   for(i=0;i<rss.length;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<rss[i].length;j++){
      
      tss[i][j]=rss[i][j];
  }
}
    
     for(k=i;k<tss.length;k++)  {
      tss[k][0]=arr[si];
  }
    
      int r=i;
      for(i=0;i<rss.length;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<rss[i].length;j++){
      
      tss[r][j+1]=rss[i][j];
      
  }
          r++;
} 
 return tss; 
    
    
}



public static int[][] subsets(int arr[]) {
   
     int start=0;
  return  returnallsub( arr,0);
    
    


}
```

}