# Generate all possible combinations of items

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

I'm making a simple game, and I wanted to make a display for the player's load out, and wanted to show every possible combination of items that they have. The player has three slots each with it's respective enum(PlayerSlotPosition). In the Item enum there are multiple values but each needing to be in a certain PlayerSlotPosition.

Example:

```
STICK(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_ONE),
STONE(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_ONE),
EGG(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_TWO),
SHOVEL(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_TWO),
PAPER(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_THREE),
DIRT(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_THREE);
```

I need to inclue the possibility that the player will not have any item equipped in any slot(or multiple slots), and this is where I am stuck. If anyone has any experience doing something like this and is willing to help me out, I would be very grateful. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is `I wanted to make a display for the player's load out, and wanted to show every possible combination of items that they have`. This reduces the complexity by a whole lot since all you have to do is print out the possible combinations of the items you have in your inventory.

```
public class EnumCombinations {

//Commenting out more than 4 items, loooong printout otherwise
public static enum ITEM{
    STICK(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_ONE),
    STONE(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_ONE),
    EGG(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_TWO),
    SHOVEL(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_TWO);
//      PAPER(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_THREE),
//      DIRT(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_THREE);
    //      DIRT(PlayerSlotPosition.SLOT_THREE);

    private ITEM(PlayerSlotPosition pos){

    }
}

public static enum PlayerSlotPosition{
    SLOT_THREE, SLOT_ONE, SLOT_TWO

}

public static List<List<ITEM>> getItemCombinations(List<ITEM> inventory){
    List<ITEM> prefix = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<ITEM>> container = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ITEM> remainder; 

    if(inventory==null){
        System.out.println("Printing all item combinations, no inventory");
        remainder =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(ITEM.values()));
    }

    else {
        remainder = new ArrayList<>(inventory);
    }
    getItemCombinations(prefix, remainder, container);
    return container;
}

private static void getItemCombinations(List<ITEM> prefix, List<ITEM> remainder, List<List<ITEM>> container){
    int n=remainder.size();

    if(remainder.isEmpty()){
        container.add(prefix);
    }

    else {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            List<ITEM> r = new ArrayList<>();
            List<ITEM> p = new ArrayList<>(prefix);
            p.add(remainder.get(i));
            for(int j=0; j<remainder.size(); j++){
                if(j==i)
                    continue;
                r.add(remainder.get(j));
            }
            getItemCombinations(p, r, container);
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getItemCombinations(null)+"\n");

    List<ITEM> playerINV = new ArrayList<>();
    playerINV.add(ITEM.STICK);
    playerINV.add(ITEM.STONE);
    playerINV.add(ITEM.EGG);
    System.out.println(getItemCombinations(playerINV));

}
}
```

Output:

```
Printing all item combinations, no inventory
[[STICK, STONE, EGG, SHOVEL], [STICK, STONE, SHOVEL, EGG], [STICK, EGG, STONE, SHOVEL], [STICK, EGG, SHOVEL, STONE], [STICK, SHOVEL, STONE, EGG], [STICK, SHOVEL, EGG, STONE], [STONE, STICK, EGG, SHOVEL], [STONE, STICK, SHOVEL, EGG], [STONE, EGG, STICK, SHOVEL], [STONE, EGG, SHOVEL, STICK], [STONE, SHOVEL, STICK, EGG], [STONE, SHOVEL, EGG, STICK], [EGG, STICK, STONE, SHOVEL], [EGG, STICK, SHOVEL, STONE], [EGG, STONE, STICK, SHOVEL], [EGG, STONE, SHOVEL, STICK], [EGG, SHOVEL, STICK, STONE], [EGG, SHOVEL, STONE, STICK], [SHOVEL, STICK, STONE, EGG], [SHOVEL, STICK, EGG, STONE], [SHOVEL, STONE, STICK, EGG], [SHOVEL, STONE, EGG, STICK], [SHOVEL, EGG, STICK, STONE], [SHOVEL, EGG, STONE, STICK]]
Printing inventory: 
[[STICK, STONE, EGG], [STICK, EGG, STONE], [STONE, STICK, EGG], [STONE, EGG, STICK], [EGG, STICK, STONE], [EGG, STONE, STICK]]
```

Please comment if I missed something in your question, this was an interesting problem.

Comment: I just need to get the possibility of the player having no item in the slot, but this is a good start for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out powersets
I guess thats what you are looking for

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

(A working power set)
[Obtaining a powerset of a set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670862/obtaining-powerset-of-a-set-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem completely. My guess is you are not really using an [Object Oriented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) approach and therefore getting stuck with Java.

So my suggestion would be to model your objects differently. E.g.:

Create interfaces for items that go in a certain slot (e.g. `SlotOneItem, SlotTwoItem`) and let the items be implementations of that interface.

```
public class Stick implements SlotOneItem {
    ...
}
```

For the slots you can then use the appropriate interface to handle items which can be stored in that slot.  E.g.:

```
public class SlotOne {
   public void setItem(SlotOneItem item) {
      ...
   }

   public SlotOneItem getItem() {
      ...
   }    
}
```

In your game you would then have instances of both the items, and I guess one of every slot, which then can be filled with items that fit in that slot, or be empty (contain `null`)