# How to find the list of all intersections of multiple sets in Java?

Tags: java, set, set-intersection, set-theory

I have a list of sets:

```
setlist = [s1,s2,s3...sn]
```

I want an all way comparison of sets, which is 2^n number of sets:

```
setIntersection = [s1 ∩ s2, s1 ∩ s2 ∩ s3, ....., s2 ∩ s3 ∩ s4, ...., sn-1 ∩ sn]
```

What would be the best way to do this in Java?

For example if I was using just 5 sets. I would want to be able to populate all overlaps of a [5 circle venn diagram.](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Symmetrical_5-set_Venn_diagram.svg)

I am trying to do this with a list of sets:

```
List<Set<People>> lListSets = new ArrayList<Set<People>>();
for (DaysObject day : listOfDaysInJanuary) {
        lListSets.add(day.peopleOneInternet());
}
findPowerSetsAndCompare(lListSets, listOfDaysInJanuary);
```

I would like find some result like:

```
January 1 (Bob, Sally, Tommy)
January 1, January 2 (Sally, Tommy)
...
so on for all possible combination of days.
```

Essentially what I am asking is how to apply a [powerset algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670862/obtaining-a-powerset-of-a-set-in-java) combined with set union.

Comment: Have you tried to use a couple of simple loops(the outer to try all possible masks, the inner to compute the intersection)?

Comment: That seems like it will get very complicated.

Comment: I don't think so. It is literally just two loops, one if statement to test if a bit is set in a mask and a method that finds an intersection of two sets.

Comment: `Set.retainAll` does the `∩` operation

Comment: then you probably can use a little recursion magic to get all combinations

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. 2 loops will do N^2 operations, which will not be enough. I need to do 2^N operations.

Comment: The first loop should iterate over all masks from 0 to 2^N - 1.

Comment: @Whitecat more than that actually, because an intersection cannot count as a single operation

Comment: Not really sure why this was closed, but here is the general idea of the  anser I was writing: 1. Make a recursive method. 2. If the input is a single set or empty list just return the empty list. 3. Else: Take out the last element `S` of the input 4. Make a copy of the input and recursively calculate the sets 'R' on it. 5. For each of the calculated sets in `R`, create a copy, retain `S`, and add the result to 'R'. 6. Add all pairs of `S` and another element in the input to 'R'. 7. Return `R`

Comment: @Whitecat I closed it because this question is essentially asking us to write a program, and there are a few ways to do it, and to recommend a library, which is specifically off topic. This question is not about a specific problem with a small portion of the code, which would be on topic. This is more about algorithms: try asking on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Bohemain I can add a specific problem with some code. But I was trying to keep it general to help whoever has this problem solve it in the future.

Comment: You know how to do the powerset, and you know how to do the intersection, so what's stopping you?

Comment: I implemented it last night. Now I am just waiting the 2 days till I am allowed to answer my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be the best way to do this in Java?

The first part you are describing is a [powerset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) (as I edited your question to include last week). You would then get the intersection for each set of sets in the powerset.

Because you are doing a powerset of sets, rather than a simple powerset of something like integers, the implementation is going to be a bit more involved.

***Extra Credit***

I wrote a basic implementation of your requirements, as an example of how you might do it. All of the methods and types in this example are members of the `Example` class.

**Example** class with just its `main` method which demonstrates the working code. I'm sure you'll forgive my using deprecated `Date` constructors for the demonstration.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create simple test harness
        Set<PeopleByDays> peepsByDay = new HashSet<PeopleByDays>();
        peepsByDay.add(new PeopleByDays(new Date(2015 - 1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 1),
            Person.BOB, Person.FRANK, Person.JIM, Person.JUDY, Person.SALLY));
        peepsByDay.add(new PeopleByDays(new Date(2015 - 1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 2),
            Person.BOB, Person.FRANK, Person.JIM, Person.JUDY, Person.TOMMY));
        peepsByDay.add(new PeopleByDays(new Date(2015 - 1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 3),
            Person.BOB, Person.FRANK, Person.JIM, Person.SALLY, Person.TOMMY));
        peepsByDay.add(new PeopleByDays(new Date(2015 - 1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 4),
            Person.BOB, Person.FRANK, Person.JUDY, Person.SALLY, Person.TOMMY));
        peepsByDay.add(new PeopleByDays(new Date(2015 - 1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 5),
            Person.BOB, Person.JIM, Person.JUDY, Person.SALLY, Person.TOMMY));

        // make powerSet, then intersect, then sort
        Set<Set<PeopleByDays>> powerPeeps = powerSet(peepsByDay);
        List<PeopleByDays> powerPeepsIntersected = intersect(powerPeeps);
        sort(powerPeepsIntersected);

        // print out results
        for (PeopleByDays peeps: powerPeepsIntersected) {
            String daysFormatted = format(peeps.getDays());
            System.out.print(daysFormatted);
            System.out.println(peeps);
        }
    }

    // all other Example members as defined in this answer
}
```

**Person** is a simple `enum` type for the people's names. Benefit of using an enum here is it takes care of appropriate `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations for desired `HashSet` behavior.

```
    static enum Person {
        BOB, FRANK, JIM, JUDY, SALLY, TOMMY;
    }
```

**PeopleByDays** extends `HashSet<Person>` to collect an additional set of `Date` objects to represent the days. Overrides `retainAll()` (intersect) to combine days; overrides `equals()` and `hashSet()` for proper behavior in outer set.

```
    static class PeopleByDays extends HashSet<Person> {
        private final Set<Date> days = new HashSet<Date>();

        public PeopleByDays() {
            super();
        }
        public PeopleByDays(Date day, Person... people) {
            super(Arrays.asList(people));
            this.days.add(day);
        }
        public PeopleByDays(PeopleByDays other) {
            super(other);
            this.days.addAll(other.days);
        }

        public List<Date> getDays() {
            return new ArrayList<Date>(this.days);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
            if (c instanceof PeopleByDays) {
                this.days.addAll(((PeopleByDays)c).days);
            }
            return super.retainAll(c);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return super.equals(o) && this.days.equals(((PeopleByDays) o).days);
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return super.hashCode() + this.days.hashCode();
        }
    }
```

**powerSet()** method, taken verbatim from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1670871/1594449).

```
    public static <T> Set<Set<T>> powerSet(Set<T> originalSet) {
        Set<Set<T>> sets = new HashSet<Set<T>>();
        if (originalSet.isEmpty()) {
            sets.add(new HashSet<T>());
            return sets;
        }
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(originalSet);
        T head = list.get(0);
        Set<T> rest = new HashSet<T>(list.subList(1, list.size()));
        for (Set<T> set: powerSet(rest)) {
            Set<T> newSet = new HashSet<T>();
            newSet.add(head);
            newSet.addAll(set);
            sets.add(newSet);
            sets.add(set);
        }
        return sets;
    }
```

**intersect()** method to create intersection for each set of sets in the powerset.

```
    static List<PeopleByDays> intersect(Set<Set<PeopleByDays>> powerSet) {
        List<PeopleByDays> intersected = new ArrayList<PeopleByDays>();
        for (Set<PeopleByDays> powerElement: powerSet) {
            PeopleByDays intersection = null;
            if (powerElement.isEmpty()) {
                intersection = new PeopleByDays();
            } else for (PeopleByDays peeps: powerElement) {
                if (intersection == null) {
                    intersection = new PeopleByDays(peeps);
                } else {
                    intersection.retainAll(peeps);
                }
            }
            intersected.add(intersection);
        }
        return intersected;
    }
```

**sort()** method to sort the resulting intersected sets by date.

```
    static void sort(List<PeopleByDays> peeps) {
        Collections.sort(peeps, new Comparator<PeopleByDays>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(PeopleByDays p1, PeopleByDays p2) {
                List<Date> days1 = p1.getDays();
                List<Date> days2 = p2.getDays();
                Collections.sort(days1);
                Collections.sort(days2);
                for (int i = 0; i < days1.size() && i < days2.size(); i++) {
                    int compare = days1.get(i).compareTo(days2.get(i));
                    if (compare != 0) {
                        return compare;
                    }
                }
                return days1.size() - days2.size();
            }
        });
    }
```

**format()** method to format the list of days for each intersection.

```
    static String format(List<Date> days) {
        if (days.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d");
        Collections.sort(days);
        String separator = "";
        for (Date day: days) {
            sb.append(separator);
            sb.append(format.format(day));
            separator = ", ";
        }
        sb.append(" ");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

And finally, the output.

```
[]
Jan 1 [BOB, JUDY, FRANK, JIM, SALLY]
Jan 1, Jan 2 [BOB, JUDY, FRANK, JIM]
Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 3 [BOB, FRANK, JIM]
Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 3, Jan 4 [BOB, FRANK]
Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 3, Jan 4, Jan 5 [BOB]
Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 3, Jan 5 [BOB, JIM]
Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 4 [BOB, JUDY, FRANK]
Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 4, Jan 5 [BOB, JUDY]
Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 5 [BOB, JUDY, JIM]
Jan 1, Jan 3 [BOB, FRANK, JIM, SALLY]
Jan 1, Jan 3, Jan 4 [BOB, FRANK, SALLY]
Jan 1, Jan 3, Jan 4, Jan 5 [BOB, SALLY]
Jan 1, Jan 3, Jan 5 [BOB, JIM, SALLY]
Jan 1, Jan 4 [BOB, JUDY, FRANK, SALLY]
Jan 1, Jan 4, Jan 5 [BOB, JUDY, SALLY]
Jan 1, Jan 5 [BOB, JUDY, JIM, SALLY]
Jan 2 [BOB, JUDY, TOMMY, FRANK, JIM]
Jan 2, Jan 3 [BOB, TOMMY, FRANK, JIM]
Jan 2, Jan 3, Jan 4 [BOB, TOMMY, FRANK]
Jan 2, Jan 3, Jan 4, Jan 5 [BOB, TOMMY]
Jan 2, Jan 3, Jan 5 [BOB, TOMMY, JIM]
Jan 2, Jan 4 [BOB, JUDY, TOMMY, FRANK]
Jan 2, Jan 4, Jan 5 [BOB, JUDY, TOMMY]
Jan 2, Jan 5 [BOB, JUDY, TOMMY, JIM]
Jan 3 [BOB, TOMMY, FRANK, JIM, SALLY]
Jan 3, Jan 4 [BOB, TOMMY, FRANK, SALLY]
Jan 3, Jan 4, Jan 5 [BOB, TOMMY, SALLY]
Jan 3, Jan 5 [BOB, TOMMY, JIM, SALLY]
Jan 4 [BOB, JUDY, TOMMY, FRANK, SALLY]
Jan 4, Jan 5 [BOB, JUDY, TOMMY, SALLY]
Jan 5 [BOB, JUDY, TOMMY, JIM, SALLY]
```

Hope that helps. I tinkered with it a lot longer than I intended ;) Still didn't sort the Person names in the output though.

Comment: Glad to help :) Besides, it's fun.