# Algorithm to get all the combinations of size n from an array (Java)?

Tags: java, combinations, combinatorics

Right now I'm trying to write a function that takes an array and an integer n, and gives a list of each size n combination (so a list of int arrays). I am able to write it using n nested loops, but this only works for a specific size of subset. I can't figure out how to generalize it to work for any size of combination. I think I need to use recursion?

This is the code for all combinations of 3 elements, and I need an algorithm for any number of elements.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class combinatorics{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
        combinations3(arr,list);
        listToString(list);
    }

    static void combinations3(int[] arr, List<int[]> list){
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-2; i++)
            for(int j = i+1; j<arr.length-1; j++)
                for(int k = j+1; k<arr.length; k++)
                    list.add(new int[]{arr[i],arr[j],arr[k]});
    }

    private static void listToString(List<int[]> list){
        for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){ //iterate through list
            for(int j : list.get(i)){ //iterate through array
                System.out.printf("%d ",j);
            }
        System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This SO question might help you
[Finding powerset][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670862/obtaining-a-powerset-of-a-set-in-java

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is a well-studied problem of generating all k-subsets, or [k-combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), which can be easily done without recursion.

The idea is to have array of size `k` keeping sequence of *indices* of elements from the input array (which are numbers from `0` to `n - 1`) in increasing order. (*Subset* then can be created by taking items by these indices from the initial array.) So we need to generate all such index sequences.

First index sequence will be `[0, 1, 2, ... , k - 1]`, on the second step it switches to `[0, 1, 2,..., k]`, then to `[0, 1, 2, ... k + 1]` and so on. The last possible sequence will be `[n - k, n - k + 1, ..., n - 1]`.

On each step, algorithm looks for the closest to the end item which can be incremented, increments it and fills up items right to that item.

To illustrate, consider `n = 7` and `k = 3`. First index sequence is `[0, 1, 2]`, then `[0, 1, 3]` and so on... At some point we have `[0, 5, 6]`:

```
[0, 5, 6] <-- scan from the end: "6" cannot be incremented, "5" also, but "0" can be
[1, ?, ?] <-- "0" -> "1"
[1, 2, 3] <-- fill up remaining elements

next iteration:

[1, 2, 3] <-- "3" can be incremented
[1, 2, 4] <-- "3" -> "4"
```

Thus, `[0, 5, 6]` is followed by `[1, 2, 3]`, then goes `[1, 2, 4]` etc.

Code:

```
int[] input = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};    // input array
int k = 3;                             // sequence length   

List<int[]> subsets = new ArrayList<>();

int[] s = new int[k];                  // here we'll keep indices 
                                       // pointing to elements in input array

if (k <= input.length) {
    // first index sequence: 0, 1, 2, ...
    for (int i = 0; (s[i] = i) < k - 1; i++);  
    subsets.add(getSubset(input, s));
    for(;;) {
        int i;
        // find position of item that can be incremented
        for (i = k - 1; i >= 0 && s[i] == input.length - k + i; i--); 
        if (i < 0) {
            break;
        }
        s[i]++;                    // increment this item
        for (++i; i < k; i++) {    // fill up remaining items
            s[i] = s[i - 1] + 1; 
        }
        subsets.add(getSubset(input, s));
    }
}

// generate actual subset by index sequence
int[] getSubset(int[] input, int[] subset) {
    int[] result = new int[subset.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < subset.length; i++) 
        result[i] = input[subset[i]];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is a nice elegant solution that I prefer over recursion. I may also try to make a recursion solution and then compare the runtimes out of curiosity. The code I ended up using was a combination of yours and the link Roney provided. The key piece of the algorithm in both solutions seems to be some form of s[i] < input.length-k+i, which is what I was unable to figure out on my own.

Comment: You're welcome. I have no idea why they put your question on hold, by the way I voted for reopen. I love recursion when there is need to traverse a tree or walk through a comparator where object include other objects, and so on. When you compare, please note!

Comment: Within the large if-statement, within the for-loop, the `else`can be removed because of the `break`. That will clean the code a little bit.

Comment: @SoS for sure. Feel free to correct.

Answer (score 6):

If I understood your problem correctly, [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/) article seems to point to what you're trying to do.

To quote from the article:

> **Method 1 (Fix Elements and Recur)**
>
> We create a temporary array ‘data[]’ which stores all outputs one by
>   one. The idea is to start from first index (index = 0) in data[], one
>   by one fix elements at this index and recur for remaining indexes. Let
>   the input array be {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and r be 3. We first fix 1 at index
>   0 in data[], then recur for remaining indexes, then we fix 2 at index
>   0 and recur. Finally, we fix 3 and recur for remaining indexes. When
>   number of elements in data[] becomes equal to r (size of a
>   combination), we print data[].
>
> **Method 2 (Include and Exclude every element)**
>
> Like the above method, We create a temporary array data[]. The idea
>   here is similar to Subset Sum Problem. We one by one consider every
>   element of input array, and recur for two cases:
>
> 1. The element is included in current combination (We put the element in data[] and increment next available index in data[])
> 2. The element is excluded in current combination (We do not put the element and do not change index)
>
> When number of elements in data[] become equal to r (size of a
>   combination), we print it.