# How to generate all possible combinations of 0-1 matrix in Python?

Tags: python, combinations

How can generate all possible combinations of a 0-1 matrix of size K by N?

For example, if I take K=2 and N=2, I get the following combinations.

```
combination 1
[0, 0;
 0, 0]; 
combination 2
[1, 0;
 0, 0]; 
combination 3
[0, 1;
 0, 0]; 
combination 4
[0, 0;
 1, 0]; 
combination 5
[0, 0;
 0, 1]; 
combination 6
[1, 1;
 0, 0]; 
combination 7
[1, 0;
 1, 0]; 
combination 8
[1, 0;
 0, 1]; 
combination 9
[0, 1;
 1, 0]; 
combination 10
[0, 1;
 0, 1]; 
combination 11
[0, 0;
 1, 1]; 
combination 12
[1, 1;
 1, 0]; 
combination 13
[0, 1;
 1, 1]; 
combination 14
[1, 0;
 1, 1]; 
combination 15
[1, 1;
 0, 1]; 
combination 16
[1, 1;
 1, 1];
```

Comment: More like an algorithm question --> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A one-liner solution with `numpy` and `itertools`:

```
[np.reshape(np.array(i), (K, N)) for i in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat = K*N)]
```

*Explanation:* the `product` function returns a Cartesian product of its input. For instance, `product([0, 1], [0, 1])` returns an iterator that comprises all possible permutations of `[0, 1]` and `[0, 1]`. In other words, drawing from a product iterator:

```
for i, j in product([0, 1], [0, 1]):
```

is actually equivalent to running two nested for-loops:

```
for i in [0, 1]:
    for j in [0, 1]:
```

The for-loops above already solve the problem at hand for a specific case of `K, N = (1, 0)`. Continuing the above line of thought, to generate all possible zero/one states of a vector `i`, we need to draw samples from an iterator that is equivalent to a nested for-loop of depth `l`, where `l = len(i)`. Luckily, `itertools` provides the framework to do just that with its `repeat` keyword argument. In the case of OP's problem this permutation depth should be `K*N`, so that it can be reshaped into a numpy array of proper sizes during each step of the list comprehension.