# How to convert type of stream?

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

In addition to my question asked previously, that can be found here,
[How to combine list elements and find the price of largest combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734400/how-to-combine-list-elements-and-find-the-price-of-largest-combination)

Instead of using `Integer price`, I am using `String price`,

```
List<Long> highest = details
                .stream()
                .map(d -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(d.getDetailId()), d.getStackableDetails().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.stream().map(Double.class::cast).reduce(0D,
                        (left, right) -> left + Double.parseDouble(map.get(right).getPrice())),
                        s -> s.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()),
                        (left, right) -> right,
                        TreeMap::new))
                .lastEntry().getValue();
```

But I keep getting a class cast exception while running the same. Can someone tell me why I'm not able to cast the Stream type and how I can rectify the same. Thanks!

Comment: post the actual failure message/stacktrace

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Long to java.lang.Double

Comment: yes, for example `String price ="30.0"`.

Comment: `detailId` is of type `Long` right?

Comment: why are your types mixed up anyway? Is that `Detail.class` under your control? If yes, adapt it accordingly. If not: why don't you wrap them into your own type first? That way you don't need to cast and parse that often...

Comment: I added an [answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43763703/6202869), where you could just add your price transformation function into...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not quite clear to me what you are trying to do, but there is no sense in populating a `TreeMap`, just to get the last element. Getting the maximum element is provided as an intrinsic `Stream` operation.

So what you are doing in the question’s code can be simplified to

```
List<Long> highest = details
    .stream()
    .map(d -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(d.getDetailId()), d.getStackableDetails().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(s -> s.stream()
                       .mapToDouble(l -> Double.parseDouble(map.get((double)l).getPrice()))
                       .sum()))
    .get();
```

This also fixes you problem by simply casting the `Long` to `double`. This will unbox the `Long` object to a `long` value, perform a widening conversion to `double` and box it to a `Double` for the `Map` lookup. However, it’s not recommended to use `Double` objects as map keys.

Comment: Did I miss something? Where did the `map` come from (`map.get((double)l)`?

Comment: @Holger `TreeMap` suggestion was me being idiotic and writing and answer in a rush... Be to blame, not the OP

Comment: @Roland: I don’t know where it comes from, but it’s in the OP’s code and I just use it exactly the same way… From the context, we can conclude that it must be a `Map<Double,String>`. Keep in mind that the OP’s code has evolved since the previous question.

Comment: @Eugene: never mind; we all do such things in a rush or when we are tired. That’s why it is so important to revise the code later on…

Comment: Eugene, Holger, Roland - Thanks for all the help folks, all these solutions work great. Thanks again!

Comment: ah, ok... wasn't there when I looked at it... so I was just wondering where I've missed it... thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most probably here:

```
 s -> s.stream().map(Double.class::cast)
```

Your `detailId` is of type `Long`; but your are trying to convert that to a `Double`.

Comment: But isn't casting from long to double valid. Please let me know what I am missing, also is there an alternate way of doing this.

Comment: casting from the primitive type `long` to the primitive type `double` is valid, but casting from `Long` to `Double` is not, as `Long` is not a subclass of `Double`. You can use `.map(Long::doubleValue)` instead.

Comment: @liksar these are `Objects` and you can't simply cast from one to another (not going to explain why - there is *a lot* of info about this). Also you might be talking about `widening` or `narrowing` which works for simple types, not Objects.

Comment: @Holger it is legal - but *might* very well lose precision, but the numbers would have to be really big.

Comment: @Eugene: that doesn’t matter when you are going to sum them up to a `double` value anyway. Using the sum as a map key make little sense anyway, regardless of its type…

Answer (score 1):

Nearly a copy of [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43763703/6202869):

```
double maxPrice = details.stream()
  .mapToDouble(detail -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(detail.getDetailsId()),
                                       detail.getStackableDetails().stream())
    .flatMap(detailId -> details.stream()
      .filter(candidateDetail -> detailId.equals(candidateDetail.getDetailsId())))
    .map(Detail::getPrice)
    // the applied transformation function of your String price to double:
    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble) 
    .sum()
  )
  .max()
  .orElse(0.0);
```