# Get all unique sequences from an array

Tags: java, arrays

Ive read many post about how to generate unique **random** sequences, yet none about how to get all unique sequences from an given array.

ex. i have an array like so: [1,2,3,4]

I need to come up with some logic on how to obtain an list of int array's containing **all** (unique) sequences that can be made from that array.
*[1,2,3,4]

[1,2,4,3]

[1,3,2,4]

[1,3,4,2]

[1,4,2,3]

[1,4,3,2]*

etc etc...

This thing is eating me, pseudo this didn't look hard at all, but either I'm missing something obvious or this is some advanced task.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you assuming that the array elements are all distinct?

Comment: Maybe this one is more complex but you will find your solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910312/algorithm-to-get-all-the-combinations-of-size-n-from-an-array-java

Comment: @johnBollinger yes, all elements are distinct.

Comment: @nguyentt Thanks, I should be able to get my solution with that helpfull thread!