# Finding every possible combination of a list of numbers divided in two sets

Tags: algorithm, set, filtering

I have a  list of numbers eg.

- 120
- 233
- 197
- 400
- 276
- 356
- 121

For the purpose of my program these numbers have to be arranged in two sets. Based on what numbers are in the set the program calculates the efficiency of each set. It then combines the efficiency quotients for the combination of the two sets. The two sets and its efficiency quotient then gets saved in an array.

The goal is to find the combination of sets where both the sets have the highest efficiency.

My problem: At the moment, i can't seem to wrap my head around the algorithm needed to check every possible set combination. As far as i can get it seems to need a form of recursion.

If you need more information let me know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: OP, I think you're after the *power set*, i.e. the set of all subsets. ([Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670862/obtaining-a-powerset-of-a-set-in-java) is a solution for how to generate that.) Now you simply iterate over each set in the power set and treat it as one half (you can ignore it if it's greater than half the original set.) You use the complement as the other half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over all possible ways in which you can form two sets, you should iterate over all possible subsets of the initial list. To do that you can use bitmask of size n, where n is the number of elements in the initial list.

To generate all possible bitmasks of size n, you can use a simple cycle(c++ code that should be easy to port to other languages):

```
for (int mask = 0; mask < (1 << (n - 1)); ++mask) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     if (mask & (1 << i)) {
       // element i is in the first sub set
     } else  {
       // element i is in the second sub set
     }
   }
   // compute efficiency quotient for these subsets
}
```

Overall complexity is 2<sup>n</sup> * efficiency_quotient calclulation and is as good as you can go unless you have additional information on the efficiency quotient.

NOTE: here I cycle up to `1 << (n - 1)` to avoid considering subsets A and B and then B and A. If the efficiency quotient cares about the order, you will need to change that to `1 << n`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After doing some iteration by hand i understand how the bitmask works and it is exactly what i was looking for.