# Print all subsets of an array recursively

Tags: java

I want to print all subsets of the generated arrays recursively in the main method.

The following lines show my Code. I don't know how to implement the method subsets() recursively.

```
public class Main {

    // Make random array with length n
    public static int[] example(int n) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] example = new int[n + 1];
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            example[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
        }
        Arrays.sort(example, 1, n + 1);
        return example;
    }

    // Copy content of a boolean[] array into another boolean[] array
    public static boolean[] copy(boolean[] elements, int n) {
        boolean[] copyof = new boolean[n + 1];
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            copyof[i] = elements[i];
        }

        return copyof;
    }

    // Counts all subsets from 'set'
    public static void subsets(int[] set, boolean[] includes, int k, int n) {

       // recursive algo needed here!

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // index starts with 1, -1 is just a placeholder.
        int[] setA = {-1, 1, 2, 3, 4};
        boolean[] includesA = new boolean[5];
        subsets(setA, includesA, 1, 4);

    }

}
```

Comment: "subsets" can be a bit ambiguous. Given the array `[1,2,3,4]`, what "subsets" would you expect?

Comment: You might want and implement `subsets()` non-recursively (i.e. implement it for _one_ subset), then think about what a recursive call should do (how do you define subsets, are they permutations?) and tell us. In the process you just might realize how you'd implement the recursion yourself.

Comment: @tobias_k like here {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {1,2,3}, {2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}

Comment: The [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)? See also [Power set: Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1670862/230513).

Comment: And how to handle duplicates? I.e., what about the array `[1,1]`? `[[], [1]]` or `[[], `[1]`, [1,1]]` or `[[], [1], [1], [1,1]]`?

Comment: @tobias_k like so `[[], [1]]`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option to use a third party library, the Guava Sets class can give you all the possible subsets. Check out [the powersets method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#powerSet-java.util.Set-).

Comment: This is no option in this case.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-recursive technique:

```
public List<Set<Integer>> getSubsets(Set<Integer> set) {
    List<Set<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();

    int numSubsets = 1 << set.size(); // 2 to the power of the initial set size

    for (int i = 0; i < numSubsets; i++) {
        Set<Integer> subset = new HashSet<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < set.size(); j++) {
            //If the jth bit in i is 1
            if ((i & (1 << j)) == 1) {
                subset.add(set.get(i));
            }
        }
        subsets.add(subset);
    }
    return subsets;
}
```

If you want only unique (and usually unordered) subsets, use a `Set<Set<Integer>>` instead of `List<Set<Integer>>`.