# create a random graph based on choosing a random subset of the power set of a set?

Tags: java

How can I use a code like one of those in [Obtaining a powerset of a set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670862/obtaining-a-powerset-of-a-set-in-java) in order to create a random graph based on choosing a random subset of the power set of a set?

Probably this question is too general, and reveals my stupidity at programming (and that I am new in java), but, I really thought that I should ask the question, and see if MAYBE I could get some hint.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear how this random subset is supposed to correspond to a graph. What should the edges be?

Comment: First, There would be a random number choosing between 0 and 10, and the result should correspond to the number of vertices (say n). The edges would then be a random subset of the complete graph of n vertices.