# How to count all possible cases?

Tags: java, algorithm

For example I have array with length n=3:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = i;
}
```

So the cases should be:

```
1. 0
2. 1
3. 2
4. 0 1
5. 0 2
6. 1 2
7. 0 1 2
```

So the number of cases should be 7 for n = 3.
In my code:

```
int n = 3;
int[] array = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array[i] = i;
}
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
    sum++;
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    sum++;
}
System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
```

Output is:

```
0 
0 1 2 
1 
1 2 
2 
2 
sum = 6
```

The number 2 is two times so it is wrong and sum is actually = 5. And I don't get cases

```
4. 0 1 
and 
5. 0 2
```

How to count all possible cases?

Comment: Math.pow(2,n) - 1?

Comment: Looks like a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

Comment: **Why the down-votes**? The question is **clear**, contains an **example**, **desired output** and the **current output**. Also OP **showed effort** by trying it first on her own and she's also showing us the code as [mcve]. Looks good to me. If she doesn't know the term "*power set*" the problem itself also is not that easy to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sets, not arrays

The first important observance is that you are not using fixed length **arrays** here but **sets** of different lengths.

Take a look at your example. You allow

```
0
1
2
0, 1
0, 2
1, 2
```

which are not all of size `3`.

Also you don't differentiate between

```
0, 1
1, 0
```

so order doesn't matter, like in **sets**.

---

### Power set

That's why you're actually describing [power sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) here. For the example set `{0, 1, 2}` its **power set** is defined as

```
P({0, 1, 2}) = {
    {}, // empty set
    {0},
    {1},
    {2},
    {0, 1},
    {0, 2},
    {1, 2},
    {0, 1, 2}
}
```

Fortunately there exists an easy **closed formula** for their size. If `n` is the size of the input set the size of the power set is

```
2^n
```

But they also count the **empty set**, so you will need to `-1` if you don't want that:

```
2^n - 1
```

---

### Solution

Thus in Java you could write

```
int Set<Integer> input = ...
int size = (int) Math.pow(2, input.size()) - 1;
```

and **that's all**, you don't need to build the contents manually.

But if you're curious and want to build them, take a look at questions like [Obtaining a powerset of a set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670862/obtaining-a-powerset-of-a-set-in-java). It's an implementation of the recursive formula shown at Wikipedia.

So, **totally inefficient** but also working:

```
int Set<Integer> input = ...

// Build the power-set using the method from linked question
Set<Set<Integer>> power = powerSet(input);

int size = power.size() - 1;
```